# Day/Night theme is not implementing correctly in android

Tags: android, layout, themes, android-appcompat, android-theme

I have implemented **android Day/Night theme** in my application and for some reasons.

1) I am **unable** to change the **color of my text** and also for making it work I have to click on toggle button and go back to main screen, that means the implementation is **not** showing in the **settings** page and have to be **refreshed** by going to Homepage

2) The second problem I am facing is that when the day/night theme is applied my **recyclerView** posts get back to **1st** in list and do not just get applied where it was.

Please help!!.

I am using Android studio

**Day/Night theme class file:**

```
public class settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ToggleButton DayNightt;
    private static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_page);
        DayNightt = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.dayNight_Switch);
        DayNightt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);


                }
            }
        });
}
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", DayNightt.isChecked());
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DayNightt.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));

    }
}
```

**color-night xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimaryNight">#222222</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDarkNight">#222222</color>
    <color name="colorAccentNight">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimaryNight">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorBackgroundNight">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

**style-night xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryNight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkNight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentNight</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackgroundNight</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimaryNight</item>

    </style>
    </resources>
```

**Style xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**color xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#824c83dd</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303f9f</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="SourceColor">#00bdbdbd</color>
    <color name="background">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is a question about code in android studio, not about android studio. DOn't use the Android Studio tag for questions about code in AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the color correction part successfully by adding the following code:

**colors xml file:**

```
<color name="TextP">#000000</color>
```

**color-night xml file:**

```
<color name="TextP">#FFFFFF</color>
```

And then assigning my text the same color as above in colors.xml

but rest of parts are still a problem to me so if anybody can help, please.

Comment: This seems to be an issue. For me sometimes Android guesses the colors right sometimes it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

What about adding in color-night.xml this string that you have used in normal color.xml? `<color name="textColorPrimary">#000000</color>`

Comment: Have added it already textColorPrimaryNight in color-night.xml